# how to clean up a col and only keep # and number

Tags: r

I try to clean up a data,and run into some difficulty.
Sample data can be built using codes:

I would like to achieve outcome 1 and 2 if it is possible. How can I do that? Please give me some guidance on this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` to extract the numeric part from the 'N1' in a `list`, then loop over the `list` with `map`, paste the `#` on the type converted values, and `collapse` them or without the `#`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    mutate(tmp = str_extract_all(N1, "\\d+"), 
    Outcome1 = map_chr(tmp, ~ str_c('#', as.numeric(.x), collapse=", ")), 
    Outcome2 = map_chr(tmp, ~ str_c(as.numeric(.x), collapse=", "))) %>%
    select(-tmp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  N1        Outcome1 Outcome2
#  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   
#1 "#7"      #7       7       
#2 "#7 #8"   #7, #8   7, 8    
#3 "#7,#8"   #7, #8   7, 8    
#4 "#07"     #7       7       
#5 "#/7"     #7       7       
#6 "#/\\7"   #7       7       
#7 "#7#8"    #7, #8   7, 8    
#8 "7 and 8" #7, #8   7, 8
```

Comment: I'll delete mine, you at least had an explanation.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think you answered it some seconds earlier, but believe me, I didn't copy from you

Comment: I have no doubts about that. I can't really imagine another good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks both. :D what if my data is more complicate? I just update my post to increase the difficulty. I sliced my data and then get number out. But i think my way is too complicated. You guys might have much better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Stataq can you please post that as a new question

Comment: Sure, Will post a new question. :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution maybe a little awkward:

1. With `as.character(gsub("[^1-9]", "", N1))` we extract the numbers and transform `N1`to character
2. Create `outcome_1`: we use the `str_length` to manipluate one digit characters and two digit characters in a `case_when` function.
3. From `outcome_1` we remove all `#` with `str_remove_all` and get `outcome_2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(helper = as.character(gsub("[^1-9]", "", N1))) %>% 
  mutate(outcome_1 = 
           case_when(str_length(helper) == 1 ~ paste("#",helper, sep = ""),
                     str_length(helper) == 2 ~ paste("#",str_sub(helper, 1, 1), ", ", "#", str_sub(helper, -1, -1), sep = ""))
         ) %>% 
  mutate(outcome_2 = str_remove_all(outcome_1, "[#]"))%>% 
  select(-helper)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  N1        outcome_1 outcome_2
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 "#7"      #7        7        
2 "#7 #8"   #7, #8    7, 8     
3 "#7,#8"   #7, #8    7, 8     
4 "#07"     #7        7        
5 "#/7"     #7        7        
6 "#/\\7"   #7        7        
7 "#7#8"    #7, #8    7, 8     
8 "7 and 8" #7, #8    7, 8
```

Data:

```
df<-structure(list(N1 = c("#7", "#7 #8", "#7,#8", "#07", "#/7", "#/\\7", 
"#7#8", "7 and 8")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```